Should 'self' be explicitly specified in closure with weak reference to self in capture list?
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    view.setNeedsLayout()
}

With above code we get expected error: Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit.
It's known that the error can be eliminated with code updated like that:
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
}

But if I don't explicitly write 'self.' before accessing 'view' would closure keep strong reference to self?
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    view.setNeedsLayout()
}

Is modern swift smart enough to deal such thing in right way automatically?

The main queue does capture the underlying task (block), and this task keeps a strong reference with self, thus there is a retain cycle here.
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.view.setNeedsLayout() //<- strong reference
}

However, it's temporary because self will be automatically released when dequeue from main queue.
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.view.setNeedsLayout() //<- after this line, self will be released and there is no retain-cycle
}

It's all about your purpose if you want to put [weak self] within the closure.

If you put [weak self] inside the closure, when the time comes, the main queue dequeues the next task. During this time self is dismissed, for example, so it will return immediately.
If you remove [weak self], the same process happens, but the self will be removed right after closure execution.

Site node: your 2nd and 3rd snippets make no difference since SE-0365.

Technically self doesn't store reference to DispatchQueue, so it's doesn't retain cycle.

@Cy-4AH ... more precisely, "Technically self doesn't store reference to the DispatchQueue.main queue". It's about the main queue, which is a singleton. A class  might use its own queue and thus keep a strong reference to it. When a method uses this queue and creates a closure which imports self, then, we do technically have a retain cycle. ;)
But you are right, in this case, there is no retain cycle.

@Cy-4AH To be clear, I mean there is a strong reference between queue block and self, and as CouchDeveloper said, not GCD and the self itself.

DispatchQueue closure don't cause retain cycle so you can use self directly, no need to use [weak self]. See this link for more details. In your third code block, the compiler will see your code the same as second block, so it is not view to be capture, it is still self to be captured

True. Doesn't know why closure in async doesn't marked with @_implicitSelfCapture yet.

@Cy-4AH  AFAIK, the decision to use self is to make it explicit that self will be captured. Whether this results in a retain cycle is a different question. A closure in a dispatch queue is NOT ALWAYS a "continuation". Only a continuation would guarantee, that it will be called eventually. Thus, a closure can stay for ever, when the conditions are not met to invoke it. This is in contrast to a Swift Task. There, the closure is a continuation.
